# How to create a custom Android layout?

Tags: android, user-interface

This is a noob Android question. I've been doing iOS development for years and I've already completed the following view in iOS, but now I'm trying to get it working for Android.

This is the layout...
[image: loaded view]

...then the user swipes the view off of the screen, and it "falls" off the screen...

[image]

...and is then replaced with a new rendering of the view...
[image: loaded view]

In iOS, I have a custom view controller that builds and populates each view. I'm trying to figure out how to get this kind of thing working in Android. I think a ViewPager might be helpful, but it would be great to get some advice before I begin. Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I should also mention that these views flow in one direction only. In other words, once they're swiped off screen, they can't come back. They're replaced with the new view with new content.

Comment: I think CircularViewPager more useful instead of Simple ViewPager Look  here how to use CircularViewPager : https://github.com/lib4/CircularViewPager

Comment: For animating transitions between pages in a `ViewPager` you should look at the `ViewPager.PageTransformer` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.PageTransformer.html

Comment: In response to your edit: you can try overriding the `canScrollHorizontally(int direction)` method to always return 'false' for whichever direction you *don't* want to scroll in. Another possibility is to simply have your pager adapter delete each page as it scrolls off-screen. Possibly a combination of the two.

Comment: Awesome, @Squonk. I'll give that a shot. Your suggestion of deleting each page is exactly what I'm doing in iOS: as soon as the old view falls off the screen, I dispose it, and then build a new one. Another animation that's not illustrated in my mockups is that the two images enter from each side upon loading, slamming into one another with a little bounce and then coming to rest. It looks pretty cool. And the falls are combined with a random rotation angle, so they feel organic and fresh each time. I hope I can achieve the same things in Android!

Comment: @NovaJoe : OK, in hindsight you might not find `ViewPager` ideal. If you are going to build each view individually then you could use `GestureOverlayView` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureOverlayView.html - that would allow you to detect swipes in any direction. You'd also want to look at View Animation https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html